# Join in magento 2 Ratings and Review

Tags: magento2, ratings, join-table, product-review

I am trying to fecth data form review and rating_option_vote.
i need all values of rating and all Rating count group by Rating Id.

```
public function getRatingSummeryByAttribute($currentProductId)
{
    $attributesValues = $this->ratingColFactory->create()
        ->addFieldToSelect('rating_id')
        ->addFieldToSelect('rating_code')
        ->getData();
    if ($attributesValues)
    {
        $totalRatingRecord = $this->_ratingFactory
            ->addFieldToFilter ('entity_pk_value', $currentProductId);
        $totalRatingRecord->getSelect()
            ->columns('SUM(value) as sum_vales')
            ->columns('count(rating_id) as total_rating')
            ->group('rating_id')->join(
                [
                    'review' => 'review'
                ],
                "main_table.review_id = review.review_id"
            )->where('status_id = 1')
        ;
echo $totalRatingRecord->getSelect()->__toString();
```

Query Printed

> SELECT `main_table`.*, SUM(value) AS `sum_vales`, count(rating_id) AS `total_rating`, `review`.* FROM `rating_option_vote` AS `main_table` INNER JOIN `review` ON main_table.review_id = review.review_id WHERE (`entity_pk_value` = '14') AND (status_id = 1) GROUP BY `rating_id`

Result :
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two table column has a common column name is **entity_pk_value**. Try following way:

```
public function getRatingSummeryByAttribute($currentProductId)
{
    $attributesValues = $this->ratingColFactory->create()
        ->addFieldToSelect('rating_id')
        ->addFieldToSelect('rating_code')
        ->getData();
    if ($attributesValues)
    {
        $totalRatingRecord = $this->_ratingFactory
            ->addFieldToFilter ('main_table.entity_pk_value', $currentProductId);
        $totalRatingRecord->getSelect()
            ->columns('SUM(value) as sum_vales')
            ->columns('count(rating_id) as total_rating')
            ->group('rating_id')->join(
                [
                    'review' => 'review'
                ],
                "main_table.review_id = review.review_id"
            )->where('status_id = 1')
        ;
echo $totalRatingRecord->getSelect()->__toString();
```

And query

```
SELECT main_table.*, SUM(value) AS sum_vales, count(rating_id) AS total_rating FROM rating_option_vote AS main_table INNER JOIN review ON main_table.review_id = review.review_id WHERE (main_table.entity_pk_value = '14') AND (status_id = 1) GROUP BY rating_id
```

Comment: what if i want to join another table like the above query result with rating table. i need rating code according to rating Id.

Comment: You can as many as you want but you need to specify which table column you want for a duplicate for avoiding ambiguous column.

Comment: should i use one more join?

Comment: i used another join, like this http://i.imgur.com/hQFlPR7.png
but i got this error http://i.imgur.com/zgSH9p1.png

Comment: use main_table.rating_id

Comment: what actually this error means? Column 'rating_id' in field list is ambiguous
does it mean that two same col exists in both tables?

Comment: yes, same column name exists in both table